# What is the reward for breaking a tomb open in Gemcraft Labyrinth?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

There are a few maps with tombs in them in the tower defence game Gemcraft Labyrinth, they are often heavily armored and take a while to break open, with a swarm of shadow monsters coming out.

I've mostly avoided opening the tombs until I am strong enough to stop these. What is the reward for opening and defeating one of the tombs? What about maps where there are more than one tomb? Do you get battle amulets, skill points if you defeat one but not the other?

Comment: Tried it out last night on a map with 1 tomb and the bonus I found was +10% to the summoning multiplier. Not sure if there are different rewards for different maps.

Comment: Is a tomb different from a nest? I just finished the second level.

Comment: Yes, a tomb is different to a nest - appears on the dungeon map as a red square, there's about 6 or 7 out of the 100 levels that I've seen that have them so far. No monsters come out until you break open the tomb by shooting or bombing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you get some extra monsters to kill. 
Also as JonathanJ mentioned you get 10% in your summon multiplier for every tomb you open. Note that all tombs are not the same. There are tombs with higher hit points and armor and the monsters they spawn are tougher to beat (Higher hit points and armor).

Generally it is good to avoid opening the tombs the first time you play a map. You will have the opportunity to come back and replay the map with higher multiplier settings when you reach a higher level.

Comment: I think the battle amulet is for destroying all monster *nests*, not *tombs*

Comment: You, Sir, are correct. The +5% amulet is for the nests and not for the tombs. There are three journal amulets when you open 15, 45 and 135 tombs that give you +1, +3 and +5 skill points